# How to echo an array in PHP? and display particular value array vale

Tags: php, arrays, echo

```
array(11) { ["statusCode"]=> string(2) "OK" ["statusMessage"]=> string(0) "" ["ipAddress"]=> string(13) "183.82.100.13" ["countryCode"]=> string(2) "IN" ["countryName"]=> string(5) "India" ["regionName"]=> string(9) "Telangana" ["cityName"]=> string(9) "Hyderabad" ["zipCode"]=> string(6) "500018" ["latitude"]=> string(7) "17.3753" ["longitude"]=> string(7) "78.4744" ["timeZone"]=> string(6) "+05:30" }
```

i want to display zipcode only

Comment: This is been answered before online and on this site. go look

Comment: no research at all, please inform yourself more

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure how your code looks but if $array is that array you have printed use

```
echo $array["zipCode"];
```

You can learn more about how arrays work here http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Please try to do your own research before posting a question though as this is a fairly standard part of the language

Comment: Edited, thanks for noticing :D

Answer (score 0):

By the look of the output you might have used the var_dump statement. Any array item can be accessed in the below manner:

```
echo $array['zipCode'];
```